# Spring AmqpAppender LOG4J not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I've created a simple **Java** Project. I'm trying to centralise logging with **Logstash** and **RabbitMQ**. But first I need to centralise my logs using RabbitMQ with AmqpAppender. But it doesn't work

**My configurations:**

- Pom dependencies:

  ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
  ```
- Log4J.xml properties

  ```
  <appender name="amqp" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender">
      <param name="ExchangeName" value="amq.rabbitmq.log" />
      <param name="ExchangeType" value="topic" />
      <param name="RoutingKeyPattern" value="logstash" />
      <param name="ApplicationId" value="logstash" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m%n" />
      </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="amqp" />
    <appender-ref ref="default.file" />
  </root>
  ```

**My rabbitmq config:**

I have an **Exchange**: amq.rabbitmq.log
with a **Binding** to a queue: 'LOG' with routing key: **logstash**

But when I try to log something, the AMQP appender is not working.
My RollingFileAppender is working fine with this config:

```
 <appender name="amqp" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender">
    <param name="ExchangeName" value="test.logs" />
    <param name="ExchangeType" value="topic" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

**EDIT:**

Some images:

Exchange: [test.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz5sL.png)

I'm using the 'test.logs' exchange

Queue binding: [LOG queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuALM.png)

Answer (score 0):

"NOT WORKING" is not much help - have you tried enabling debug logging for `org.springframework.amqp`?

Have you bound a queue to `amq.rabbitmq.log`?

What routing key?

BTW, that exchange is intended for internal rabbitmq logging for retrieval, not for user logging. In fact, the admin UI doesn't even have a "publish message" dialog on [the exchange](http://localhost:15672/#/exchanges/%2F/amq.rabbitmq.log) so I suspect you can't publish to it from an external source.

I just bound a queue to it and see messages like:

```
accepting AMQP connection <0.7744.183> (127.0.0.1:65004 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
```

(i.e. broker logs).

Create your own exchange and bind a queue to it.

Comment: I've changed the exchange and the queue (check links/images). Still nothing happens

Comment: Since `test.logs` is a `topic` exchange, you need to bind with a routing key (`#` for all messages, or `logstash` from your configuration); or change the exchange type to `fanout`, which needs no routing key. See the rabbitmq tutorials to understand the exchange types and the routing key needs.